# Centre Slides using Slick-JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, slick.js

New to using Slick-JS so please forgive the obvious question.

How would I centre my slides on this page? [screenshot of slide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idk0d.png)

As you can see the slides are at the top left of the container (I've put a border around the container to make it easier to see). I would love for them to be centred in the middle of the page. I'm sure its probably something quite simple.

My code looks like this at the moment:

```
<body>
  <section class = "slick">
  <ul class = "slider">
    <li>
      <h1>Slide 1</h1>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h1>Slide 2</h1>
    </li> 
    <li>
      <h1>Slide 3</h1>
    </li> 
    <li>
      <h1>Slide 4</h1>
    </li> 
    <li>
      <h1>Slide 5</h1>
    </li> 
    <li>
      <h1>Slide 6</h1>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h1>Slide 7</h1>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h1>Slide 8</h1>
    </li> 
    <li>
      <h1>Slide 9</h1>
    </li>  
  </ul>
  <div class="container">
    <button class="prev slick-arrow"> < </button>
    <button class="next slick-arrow"> > </button>
</div>
</section>

  <script src = "/app.js"></script>
  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
 $('.slider').slick({
  dots: true,
  centermode: true,
  infinite: true,
  speed: 300,
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 3,
  prevArrow: $('.prev'),
  nextArrow: $('.next'),
  responsive: [
    {
      breakpoint: 1024,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 3,
        infinite: true,
        dots: true
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 600,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 2,
        slidesToScroll: 2
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 480,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1
      }
    }
    // You can unslick at a given breakpoint now by adding:
    // settings: "unslick"
    // instead of a settings object
  ]
})})
</script>
```

And my CSS is below:

```
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.slider {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.container{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.slider h1 {
  border: 2px solid white;
  width: 10rem;
  height : 10rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

It's too easy, you need to add this in your css:

.slider {text-align:center}

Comment: I've tried this but doesn't seem to have worked. The slides are where they were before.

Comment: Try to add '!important' after the css rule  or if you use bootstrap add the class="text-center" after  the class 'slider' of <ul> tag.
On my pc it works, if you want more help you need to share a codepen

Comment: I've solved the issue now, many thanks for your help!